# How can I read a folder of imap open?

Tags: php, imap

I have to show emails by folders. I tried:

```
$this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.':'.$this->string.'}'.$folder, $this->username, $this->password);
```

If `$folder` is `INBOX` or `""`, it's OK, but when I try a listed folder name, like `Drafts`, imap returns `"Mailbox does not exist, or must be subscribed to.".`

What did I wrong?

Comment: imap_reopen returns: Can't open mailbox Drafts: no such mailbox.

Comment: What server is it?  If it's Gmail, the folders are named something like "[Gmail]/Drafts".  You should do a LIST command to see the actual name of the mailboxes.

Comment: Ok, half of problem is solved. Regular email needs "INBOX." But how can I open the Gmail mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Max for the comment!

Regular email: `imap_open('{'.$this->server.':'.$this->string.'}INBOX.'.$f, $this->username, $this->password);`

Gmail: `imap_open('{'.$this->server.':'.$this->string.'}'.$f, $this->username, $this->password);`

With the full name: `[Gmail]/Trash`